# Gson showing nested Object as null

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, nested-object

Im trying to deserialize objects into JSON, one object contains a nested object. I created an instance of both the nested object (`UserAddress`)and the one containing it (`UserObjectWithNestedObject`). However, when I serialize, the nested object is null. So I ran the program in debugger mode to see when it goes null.

It seems to be null when I use it as a field when instantiating the `UserObjectWithNestedObject` class but I dont know why because I instantiated in the objects in the same scope so you'd think the they would be able to communicate with no issue

[image] Sorry, you might need to zoom

My classes

Main

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        serializeUserObjectWithNestedObject();
    }

    public static void serializeUserObjectWithNestedObject(){

        UserAddress userAddress = new UserAddress(
                "std",
                "000",
                "Dulin",
                "Ireland"
        );

        UserObjectWithNestedObject uowno= new UserObjectWithNestedObject(

                "thanss",
                "j@f.com",
                21,
                true,
                userAddress
        );

        System.out.println( "\nthis is the UserAddress object "+userAddress);

        String theJson = new Gson().toJson(uowno, UserObjectWithNestedObject.class);

        System.out.println(theJson);
    }

}
```

UserObjectWithNestedObject

```
public class UserObjectWithNestedObject {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private boolean isDeveloper;

    //This is the object inside this object
    public UserAddress userAddress;

    public UserObjectWithNestedObject(String name, String email, int age, boolean isDeveloper, UserAddress userAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.isDeveloper = isDeveloper;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserObjectWithNestedObject{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", isDeveloper=" + isDeveloper +
                ", userAddress=" + userAddress +
                '}';
    }
}
```

UserAddress (this is the nested object that turns null)

```
public class UserAddress {

    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    public UserAddress( String houseNumber, String city, String country, String street) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.street = street;

    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }

    public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserAddress{" +
                "street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", houseNumber='" + houseNumber + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize it :)

```
public UserObjectWithNestedObject(String name, String email, int age, boolean isDeveloper, UserAddress userAddress) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.age = age;
    this.isDeveloper = isDeveloper;
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. Just needed another pair of fresh eyes. Thank @Susan Mustafa...